# geoviews/geopandas/shapely problem displaying polygons from a shapefile

Tags: shapely, holoviz, geoviews

I am trying to overlay a shapefile representing the range of Coast Redwoods onto some other data I'm processing in [geoviews](https://geoviews.org/).  I can successfully plot the data using cartopy and matplotlib.  GeoPandas reads the shapefile, but passing the GeoDataFrame or individual shapely polygons to  gv.Shape (as in the geoviews [user guide](https://geoviews.org/user_guide/Geometries.html) under "Shape") consistently results in

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xy'
```

I am not sure whether the problem is in Shapely or in Geoviews.  I suspect geoviews because geopandas is able to reproject and plot the polygons.

I've [put up a notebook](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/m2319/redwoods_map_geoviews.html) demonstrating the problem and providing the shapefile.

Any help or ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, then i went ahead and converted my GeoDataFrame to EPSG:4326 as follows:

```
projected_df = original_df.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
```

Originally I was in EPSG:4269 (Albers Equal Area) and thought adding that to an Albers Equal Area projection would work but I think you need to start your data with EPSG:4326 and then work with projections with Geoviews.

Let me know if that does the trick.